# Creating preset users (like admin) without REGISTERING

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I want to build a small app which connects to a DB and from where you can manipulate that DB.

I am using MongoDB with Node, with passport, passport-local, mongoose. In order to access this app, you need to login but I don't want a register page. I want to add users myself in mongo. (because registering isn't open to anyone and I want only like 4-5 users)

I will make a db in Mongo with 2 collections: 1 which contains the users and 1 which will contain the data.

My problem is how to build the users collection/table without the register page? I don't know how to hash the password and do all the things without the register page, just by myself. I think I can insert each user with a name and a password, and if the password entered on the app equals with the one in the database it will log the person in.
But that will defeat the purpose of passport, password hashing and ect.

So my question is: how to create preset users without a register page in my case? What would be the best way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you know how to create users with a registration page, why can't you apply the same logic in a command line script?

Comment: Can I just use this?  "User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password)" - that's how I would do it in the post route. (and changing req.body.username and password with the desired input)

Comment: You haven't shown any code at all, so I don't know if that will cover all your bases, but presumably if you've accounted for password hashing and salting and so on in the User objects, then yes.